# Помогите с правильным юнит тестом

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

```
using System;

namespace mirrors
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate void GetMessage(); 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {

                Console.WriteLine("введiть будь який текст");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                string output = Reverse(input);
                Console.WriteLine("mirror text");
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                Console.Read();

            }
        }
        public static string Reverse(string s)
        {

            {
                char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(charArray);
                return new string(charArray);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вы собрались тестировать?

Comment: дали задания и толком никогда не писал, без понятия как реализовать. В общем что делает етот метод, просто зеркально отображает текст, как идея ето проверка первой буквы

Comment: Ну вроде всё просто, готовим начальные данные, например, `var input = "123456";`, выполняем тестируемый метод: `var output = Reverse(input);`, проверяем результат: `Assert.AreEqual("654321", output);`

Comment: а разве `static` тестируют, может надо сделать отдельный класс со свойством `public string Reverse(string s)` и уже непосредственно его и тестировать?

Comment: @Monomax, ну а почему бы не протестировать? Если вы пишете функцию вычисления синуса, нужно ли ее делать методом экземпляра? Или она заведомо правильно работает?

Comment: Тестируют. Просто считается нехорошим тоном загонять всё в статики, потому что потом мокать будет невозможно этот код, если понадобится. А так - да, например, на extension методы юнит-тесты видел, сам иногда пишу. Тут кстати я бы именно написал extension, а не класс-пустышку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из самых типовых подходов - это методика Arrange-Act-Assert:

> Модель тестов Arrange-Act-Assert представляет целую парадигму
>   тестирования, которая используется многими фреймворками юнит-тестов:
>
> ```
> Arrange: устанавливает начальные условия для выполнения теста
>
> Act: выполняет тест (обычно представляет одну строку кода)
>
> Assert: верифицирует результат теста
> ```

Вот вам пример по методу ААА на базе фреймворка nUnit:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ReverseStringTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Reverse_Always_ReturnsReversed()
    {
        // Arrange

        // Act
        var result = Program.Reverse("123456");

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("654321", result);
    }
}
```

Стадия Arrange у вас отсутствует, так как у вас static class.

Также можете написать тест для случая, когда у вас метод получит на вход null. В вашем текущем коде вы получите NullReferenceException - а возможно вам стоит возвращать null или кидать своё собственное исключение.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Модель тестов Arrange-Act-Assert](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/22.3.php)